# Preparation for building a e-news mail sending system?

Tags: email, web-applications

Recently i decided to build this kind of web application. But i have got no experience for this.
So, to begin with,
Are those system using SMTP function and include those mail plugin such as PHPmailer??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options at your disposal.

- Roll your own SMTP server + use a pre-built library relevant to your language/framework (PHPmailer)
- Purchase the services of an email service provider

If you want to go with the second, you are giving up direct control so that you won't have to maintain an SMTP server, the emails will get into inboxes without question, and you'll get detailed statistics about what you are sending and what people are doing with it.

With the second option, you have two types: transactional and bulk.

Transactional Mail Providers:

- [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com)
- [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com)
- [PostmarkApp](http://postmarkapp.com)

Bulk Mail Providers:

- [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com)
- [AWeber](http://aweber.com)
- [Exact Target](http://exacttarget.com)
- [Constant Contact](http://constantcontact.com)

Take a look at your service and determine what sort of mail you will be sending (most likely bulk) and pick your provider based on the features you will be needing.

Comment: thx, can i use google app engine ?? And in what ways it helps?

Comment: You probably could use the built in SMTP of Google App Engine, but that's similar to rolling your own because you get none of the deliverability guarantees and reporting that other services provide.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is "propably", since you can't know about all systems. The easiest way to get answer is to look at similar OSS projects source code.